# I have been trying to merge 2 sorted linked lists using C++ but my output shows nothing ,just blank?

Tags: c++, merge, linked-list, sortedlist

I have been trying to merge 2 sorted linked lists using C++ but my output shows nothing, just blank.

In main function, I created 2 sorted linked lists and in the `mergeem` function I joined them by making `h` (head) pointer and `t` (tail) pointer and incrementing the `t` pointer after it is decided which value will come next in the new joined linked list. `mergeem` returns `h` and I print the linked list with `h` as head.

Which part of my code is leading to a blank output?

```
class node
{
public:

int data;
node* next;

node(int d)
{
    data=d;
}
};

node* mergeem(node *h1,node *h2)
{
node*h;
node*t;
if(h1->data<h2->data)
    {
        h=h1;
        t=h1;
        h1=h1->next;
    }
    else
    {
        h=h2;
        t=h2;
        h2=h2->next;
    }
while(h1!=NULL && h2!=NULL)
{
    if(h1->data<h2->data)
    {
        t->next=h1;
        t=h1;
        h1=h1->next;
    }
    else
    {
        t->next=h2;
        t=h2;
        h2=h2->next;
    }
}

 while(h1!=NULL)
 {
    t->next=h1; 
 }

  while(h2!=NULL)
 {
    t->next=h2; 
 }

return h;
}
void print(node*head)
{  
node*temp=head;
cout<<"All elements : "<<endl;
 while(temp!=NULL)
 {
 cout<<temp->data<<endl;
 temp=temp->next;
 }
}
int main()
{
 node*newnode1=new node(10);
 node*newnode2=new node(15);
 node*newnode3=new node(20);
 node*newnode4=new node(25);
 node*newnode5=new node(30);
 
 newnode1->next=newnode2;
 newnode2->next=newnode3;
 newnode3->next=newnode4;
 newnode4->next=newnode5;
     
 node*ewnode1=new node(8);
 node*ewnode2=new node(12);
 node*ewnode3=new node(21);
 node*ewnode4=new node(27);
 node*ewnode5=new node(28);
 
 
 ewnode1->next=ewnode2;
 ewnode2->next=ewnode3;
 ewnode3->next=ewnode4;
 ewnode4->next=ewnode5;
 
 node*head=mergeem(newnode1,ewnode1);
 
 print(head);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to overload ostream (instead of `print`); use initialiser lists; and ensure the lists are properly linked. One trick to do this is to use a debugger rather than just `print`ing things.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that `h1` is not null after the main loop of `mergeem`.
Then the loop

```
while(h1!=NULL)
{
    t->next=h1; 
}
```

will never terminate, since the value of `h1` doesn't change; you're just assigning the same value to `t->next` over and over.
The same reasoning applies to the loop with `h2`.

Since you just want to "take over" the tail of the remaining list, you should write `if` instead of `while` in both cases.

```
if (h1 != NULL)
{
    t->next = h1; 
}
```

You could also condense the tail-stealing to

```
t->next = h1 != NULL ? h1 : h2;
```